# How to get notification in Visual Studio that unit tests failed?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, test-explorer

I have set up my local Visual Studio (VS2012) to run tests after I build. That works OK, however to see the test results, I have to manually open the TestExplorer. Is there a way to either open the TestExplorer automatically, or show something on screen, or play some sound, when the tests fail?

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same functionality but could not find it. Extended an existing VS extension that came close.

You can find my extension and source code here:
https://github.com/sboulema/vsdingextension

Code snippet on how to check test results:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    ...

    var operationState = componentModel.GetService<IOperationState>();
    operationState.StateChanged += OperationStateOnStateChanged;
}

private void OperationStateOnStateChanged(object sender, OperationStateChangedEventArgs operationStateChangedEventArgs)
{
    if (operationStateChangedEventArgs.State.HasFlag(TestOperationStates.TestExecutionFinished))
    {
        var testOperation = ((TestRunRequest)operationStateChangedEventArgs.Operation);
        if (testOperation.DominantTestState == TestState.Failed)
        {
            // Test failed, show a notification
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you at least describe your method here?

Comment: Added code on how to get the result of a text execution